# How to migrate Azure server including IIS sites with the same name, different DNS

Tags: iis, dns, migration, windows-server, azure-cloud-services

We currently have a Classic VM whose IP is directed by the DNS subdomains `app.mydomain.com` and `api.mydomain.com`. The IIS server has configured the sites `app.mydomain.com` and `api.mydomain.com`. Any user in the internet can visit both sites.

The goal is to migrate to another VM, basically creating a replica, creating two DNS subdomains `app2.mydomain.com` and `api2.mydomain.com` pointing to the new VM's IP address. As a result, visiting https://app2.mydomain.com should result in the same exact experience but be served from the new VM. Once all is tested, we would just redirect the DNS of `app.mydomain.com` to the new machine.

This is in theory because the IIS sites in the new VM are still called `app.mydomain.com` and `api.mydomain.com`, which will probably conflict with the DNS (app2, api2).

Are there any best practices for migrating VMs this way? There is no database involved (there is, but on a different server)

Comment: This question may be better suited for https://serverfault.com/, since it’s less about coding and more about system/network administration

Comment: Thanks, I [just did](https://serverfault.com/questions/1116898/how-to-migrate-azure-server-including-iis-sites-with-the-same-name-different-dn). It's funny because Azure's support sends you here, which I also found strange.